# Set allowed referer to chrome-extension protocol

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way to set allowed referers to a chrome extension url?
My chrome extension's quote exploded yesterday (40Mn in one day) and I believe someone is trying to manipulate with my youtube API key. How do I make sure that my api key can only be used in my chrome extension url, such as `chrome-extension://<extensionID>` ?